# correctly lagging with irregularly spaced data

Tags: r

I have some irregularly spaced data, say table A. The frequency is every 2-5 days. I have another data set, table B, which has entries for every weekday. I want to run the following regression:

A_{t} = alpha + beta1 * B_{t-2 months} + error

where, when I lag B, if there isn't something that isn't exactly 60 days ago, e.g. if 60 days ago was a Sunday, then just pick the next Monday. I can of course construct this w/ a for loop, but what is the R way. Currently, the data are store in MySQL tables and I am using RMySQL to access.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) package and its documentation --- which has numerous examples about how to aggregate, align, transform, ... data along the time dimension.

It is a hard problem.  You'll have to think about how you do it --- but at least appropriate and powerful tools exist.  There are also plenty of usage examples here and on the R lists.

At a minimum, you could use `na.locf()` to carry your last irregular observation forward to the next regular one (after having merged the data based on daily dates).  You can then use `lag()` operators on the regular data.  Also, packages [dynlm](http://cran.r-project.org/package=dynlm) and [dyn](http://cran.r-project.org/package=dyn) facilitate modeling with `lm()` on data help in `zoo` objects by adding lags etc to the formula interface.